# Selecting a Python Class

Tags: python, class

I have some servers of varying age here that are running varying versions of Python. On these servers I am running a script that requires MySQL interaction. I have written a wrapper class that uses the Python MySQLdb module, but on the older servers this module doesn't exist. To get around this, I'd like to find if the MySQL module exists on the server, if it does then use my wrapper class as normal, otherwise switch to a backup MySQL class that I've written using bash.

My question is: Is there an elegant way of switching between two classes like this?

The only way I can think of is to have a bunch of "if" statements inside my MySQL wrapper class which switches between different functions according to whether or not the MySQLdb module is loaded, but that seems a little messy. The important point is that the script is unaware of which of the two classes it is using, the code in the script itself must be the same regardless. I'm new to Python so thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: "On these servers I...." Is the script written in python? If so, you can use inheritance in python and this reduces the clutter and the if-else can be changed to indirection based call. Classic design patter principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both modules have the same API, the usual way is to import one of them under some common name:

```
try:
    import MySQLdb as mysql
except ImportError:
    import mymodule as mysql
```

and then use that name as usual.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could "import as" :-)